# Group pandas DataFrame by index substrings

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     nt
a    2
a1   4
a4   7
b    1
c1   10
c2   0
c4   3
```

I would like to add `nt` for index values `a, a1, a4,` and those for index values `c1, c2 and c4` and so on. I would like to see the following result:

```
a    13
b    1
c    13
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.extract('^(\D*)')[0].values)['nt'].sum()
```

Output:

```
a    13
b     1
c    13
Name: nt, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for your data:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str[0]).sum()

   nt
a  13
b   1
c  13
```

Slightly more generalised, removes all digits (not just trailing ones):

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.replace(r'\d+', '')).sum()

   nt
a  13
b   1
c  13
```